# .htaccess Rewrite to Codeigniter system in its own folder

Tags: php, apache, .htaccess, codeigniter, mod-rewrite

I built an open-source system without a MVC framework.
It became time to upgrade the system and I rebuilt it into the Codeigniter MVC framework.

The system is located in the /ci folder.
For technical reason it should stay in this folder.

I have set up the correct .htaccess in route folder to make this work:

```
    RewriteEngine on
# Change example.com to be your main domain.
RewriteCond %{HTTP_HOST} ^(www.)?domain.com$
# Change 'subdirectory' to be the directory you will use for your main domain.
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_URI} !^/ci/
# Don't change the following two lines.
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-f
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-d
# Change 'subdirectory' to be the directory you will use for your main domain.
RewriteRule ^(.*)$ /ci/$1
# Change example.com to be your main domain again.
# Change 'subdirectory' to be the directory you will use for your main domain
# followed by / then the main file for your site, index.php, index.html, etc.
RewriteCond %{HTTP_HOST} ^(www.)?domain.com$
RewriteRule ^(/)?$ ci/index.php [L] 
RewriteRule ^/member$ /member [L]
RewriteRule ^/ad_images$ /ad_images [L]
RewriteRule ^/ad_images/130$ /ad_images/130 [L]
RewriteRule ^/ad_images/116$ /ad_images/116 [L]
```

I am bypassing the member folder as Its still in use and also allow the system to make use of the different ad_images folders.

My problem is this. The old site will have a link that looks like

> www.domain.com/vehicles-for-sale

In the new system this link is actually

> www.domain.com/categories/1-0-0-0

I will need to do a permanently move the old url to the new.

Why would adding this to the .htaccess file not work and how should I write it do have the desired effect?

```
RewriteRule ^/vehicles-for-sale$ /ci/categories/index/3-0-0-0 [L]
```

Comment: htaccess is per-dir context, so "^/" will never match, you need to match ^something instead. Avoid .htaccess at all costs. It's not a rewrites depot!

Comment: @ezra-s why would you say to avoid .htaccess at all costs?
What would the other option be to do permanent rewrites?

Comment: for starters .htaccess has nothing to do with "rewrites". It is a method, so a non-admin user can set directives in certain directories, there can be rewrites, but there can be other directives too not related at all to rewrites, depends on the value set in AllowOverride by the admin. For permanent Rewrites/Redirects you can perfectly do them in virtualhost context saving you from the overhead of httpd having to check each .htaccess files at least 3 times per hit and also from the added complexity of defining redirects in per-dir context, as you have just experienced.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You should omit the first slash. And if you want to do a permanent redirect, use the `R=301` flag. Furthermore, you are rewriting to `ci/categories/index/3-0-0-0` now, instead of the desired `categories/1-0-0-0`.

This should work for you:

```
RewriteRule ^vehicles-for-sale$ /categories/1-0-0-0 [L,R=301]
```